# Отключение звука NFC android java

Tags: java, android, nfc

подскажите пожалуйста, читаю и записываю карты mifare classic, использую intent
OnCreat:

```
mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
        try {
            ndef.addDataType("*/*");
        } catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
        }
        mFilters = new IntentFilter[]{ndef,};
        mTechLists = new String[][]{new String[]{MifareClassic.class
                .getName()}};
         
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        resolveIntent(intent);
```

Также

```
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mFilters,
                mTechLists);
    введите сюда код
}
```

Как я могу отключить стандартные звуки при считывании?